# Find intrisic camera matrix from gazebo model

Tags: gazebo, opencv, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I made a my camera model in gazebo and I want to extract the intrinsic matrix to use Opencv matrix.
Here is my model:

```
<gazebo reference="camera">
    <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
    <sensor type="camera" name="camera">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <camera name="head">
        <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>1280</width>
          <height>720</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.02</near>
          <far>300</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>mdt/camera1</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>camera</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

My intrinsic matrix is define like that :
M = [ ax 0 cx; 0 ay cy ; 0 0 1 ]
I think that cx = 1280 /2  and cy = 720/2 but what about ax/ay ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377196/find-intrisic-camera-matrix-from-gazebo-model/) by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2021-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the intrinsics by subscribing to the `/camera_info` topic defined in the plugin:

> `<cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>`

The [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) message will contain the camera matrix:

> ```
> # Intrinsic camera matrix for the raw (distorted) images.
> #     [fx  0 cx]
> # K = [ 0 fy cy]
> #     [ 0  0  1]
> # Projects 3D points in the camera coordinate frame to 2D pixel
> # coordinates using the focal lengths (fx, fy) and principal point
> # (cx, cy).
> float64[9]  K # 3x3 row-major matrix
> ```

Also, you can explicitly set the intrinsics in Gazebo as indicated in the [camera SDF specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.8&elem=sensor#lens_intrinsics):

---

###Update:

Note the ROS plugin and Gazebo sensor use [two separate intrinsic parameter sets](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/872), so it's on the user to make sure they are correct.  The ROS plugin [source code](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera_utils.cpp) shows how it uses the parameters only to fill the camera info.  Here's an exampe:

```
<sensor type="camera" name="camera">
  <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
  <camera name="head">
    <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
    <image>
      <width>800</width>
      <height>800</height>
      <format>R8G8B8</format>
    </image>
    <clip>
      <near>0.02</near>
      <far>300</far>
    </clip>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
           That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
           channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.007</stddev>
    </noise>
    <lens>
      <intrinsics>
        <fx>100</fx>
        <fy>100</fy>
        <cx>640</cx>
        <cy>360</cy>
        <s>0</s>
      </intrinsics>
    </lens>
  </camera>
  <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
    <cameraName>rrbot/camera1</cameraName>
    <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
    <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
    <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
    <Cx>640</Cx>
    <Cy>360</Cy>
    <focalLength>100</focalLength>
  </plugin>
</sensor>
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on 2021-04-29**:
Indeed I can't get the intrinsic matrix like this. Thank you. About the SDF camera specifications. I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot>
      <gazebo reference="camera">
        <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
        <sensor type="camera" name="camera">
          <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
          <camera name="head">
         .....
              <near>0.2</near>
              <far>600</far>
            </clip>
            <lens>
                <intrinsics>
                        <fx>100</fx>
                        <fy>100</fy>
                        <cx>640</cx>
                        <cy>360</cy>
                        <s>0</s>s>
                </intrinsics>
            </lens>
          </camera>
```

I get this:

```
Warning [parser.cc:950] XML Element[intrinsics], child of element[lens] not defined in SDF. Ignoring[intrinsics]. You may have an incorrect SDF file, or an sdformat version that doesn't support this element.
```

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-29**:\

> Indeed I can't get the intrinsic matrix like this.

Why not?

As for the SDF, I don't get that error.  Maybe you have a different Gazebo/SDF version.  I updated my answer with an example.

**Comment by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on 2021-04-29**:
Sorry I made a error when I wrote that. I CAN get the intrinsic file . Thank you.

**Comment by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on 2021-04-30**:
I try to add the intrinsics parameters like in your example. The problem is the horizontal FOV had to be defined also with the intrinsic parameters, which is not consistent. If I not specify horizontal FOV, it use the default HFOV and I get that warning (and the camera info is not published):

```
[ WARN] [1619767559.786164054]: The <focal_length>[1067.000000] you have provided for camera_ [camera] is inconsistent with specified image_width [1280] and HFOV [1.047000].   Please double check to see that focal_length = width_ / (2.0 * tan(HFOV/2.0)), the explected focal_lengtth value is [1108.765426], please update your camera_ model description accordingly.
```

So I just use that formula to set the HFOV and to fill the matrix and not the intrinsic section which is useless...

**Comment by [Anvesh Som](https://answers.ros.org/users/52467/anvesh-som/) on 2022-01-24**:
Thanks for the tip about FOV, but I still cannot solve the problem with the parser not parsing the intrinsics tag and ignoring it. Child of lens tag.

**Comment by [noah](https://answers.ros.org/users/109349/noah/) on 2022-06-27**:
It seems that your issue is that you have `<s>0</s>s>` rather than `<s>0</s>` as one of the children of `<intrinsics>`